# How to change axis text into italic letters in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I want the species names in my plot to appear in italic letters. So far, only the first name appears repeatedly on the x axis. Also, the text of the x axis is somehow not quite in the right place, how can I adapt that?
I wrote following script:

```
boxplot(distance~bymedian,data=model1,col="lightgrey",las=2,ylab="Direct distance [m]",
        par(mar=c(8,4,3,2)+0.25),cex.axis=0.8,xaxt="n")

axis(1,at=seq(1,14,by=1),labels=FALSE)

text(seq(1,14,by=1),par("usr")[3],-0.2,pos=2,srt=60,xpd=TRUE,cex.axis=0.8,labels=expression(italic("Alphonsea sp.","unknown","Alphonsea boniana","Embelia subcoriacea","Uvaria sp.",
                             "Mitrephora vandaeflora","Orophea polycarpa","Ardisia nervosa","Diospyros sp.",
                             "Cananga latifolia","Canthium umbellatum","Phoebe paniculata","Afzelia xylocarpa","Diospyros glandulosa")))
```

Thank you so much for any advice!

Comment: what about using parameter `font`? (for italic: `font=3`)

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine!! But I still have the issue of the x axis labels not being in the right place.. what exactly does the par("usr") do?

Comment: see `?par`: *A vector of the form c(x1, x2, y1, y2) giving the extremes of the user coordinates of the plotting region. When a logarithmic scale is in use (i.e., par("xlog") is true, see below), then the x-limits will be 10 ^ par("usr")[1:2]. Similarly for the y-axis.*